# grunt watchers - how to pass parameters from parent to child processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I've got an application with quite complex grunt environment. During my build, I pass lots of parameters and options. One of them is the directory where the output is gonna be built (currently it's just a timestamp).

The great issue I find in grunt is that grunt-contrib watch doesn't share options and parameters among parent and child processes. That is, if I generate the timestamp-nameddirectory and save it inside the grunt.config, the child process just doesn't have it. In my case it generates another timestamp-named directory, but it's not about timestamps.

Mainly, the question is - how can I pass some information between parent and child processes in grunt?

Comment: Is there a way to avoid spawning child processes? Repo says that `Spawning [...] cripples tasks that rely on the watch task to share the context with each subsequent run (i.e., reload tasks). If you would like a faster watch task or need to share the context please set the spawn option to false.` Probs not the answer you're looking for (sorry!).

Comment: @userNaN the problem with spawn:false is that it fails undeterministicly. See `Not spawning task runs can make the watch more prone to failing so please use as needed.` at [grunt-contrib-watch docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionsspawn). First I started with spawn:false, but my watchers were simply not starting and this is unacceptable :( Mainly, I need the comfort (**sharing context**) of `spawn:false` and **stability** of `spawn:true`. I'm pretty sure this "prone to failing" is kinda async race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use `spawn:false`.

I've read your comments, but I've got a pretty complex buid process too, and use `spawn:false` for the exact same reason as you (specify a timestamped build output dir), and I never experienced any stability issue with my watchers.

So I really think your best bet is to set it back to false and then solve the watcher issues instead of the other way around: Ccould you do that and update the question with said issues?